# Cocoa NSImage imageNamed not working

Tags: ios, nsimageview

I'm trying to load an image in a `NSImageView`.

`[self.background setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"button_selected.png"]];`

where background is a `NSImageView`. 
The bizarre behavior is that I can't view this image unless I create another `NSImageView` by InterfaceBuilder and add the same image to it.
Yeah, same image in another `NSImageView` make my programmatically `NSImageView` work!

Any ideas?!

Comment: Can you show your code here?

Comment: Nothing very special to add here. I set this Image. 
If i add another NSImageView via InterfaceBuilder and select the same image: both image are loaded
If i don't: my image won't be loaded.
Very strange behavior

Comment: if you are programmatically add a UIImageview than you have to add self.view addsubview.

Comment: sure i did! I repeat that if i add another image, all works fine!